# Инкапсуляция в ООП

Tags: java, ооп

Необходимо написать класс который будет подсчитывать среднюю успеваемость студентов по пяти экзаменам используя ООП.
Вот что я написал в **классе Sudent:**

```
public class Student
{
    protected int examMark1;
    protected int examMark2;
    protected int examMark3;
    protected int examMark4;
    protected int examMark5;

    public Student(int examMark1, int examMark2, int examMark3, int examMark4, int examMark5)
    {
        this.examMark1 = examMark1;
        this.examMark2 = examMark2;
        this.examMark3 = examMark3;
        this.examMark4 = examMark4;
        this.examMark5 = examMark5;
    }

    public int getAveregeMarkForStudent()
    {
        int exams = 5;
        int result = (examMark1 + examMark2 + examMark3 + examMark4 + examMark5) / exams;
        return result;
    }
}
```

И в классе **Main** я делаю примерно так:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student(8, 12, 3, 6, 2);
        System.out.println(student.getAveregeMarkForStudent());

    }
}
```

Но вопрос в том, а что если у меня будет не 5 экзаменов, а например 150, и количество студентов будет, например 500, тогда нужно будет прописывать все. Я не могу понять как необходимо сделать что бы программа производила расчеты не зависимо от количество экзаменов и количества студентов.

Comment: Контейнеры определенно позволят написать метод вычисления среднего значения его элементов. Сразу меньше мороки.

Comment: А что если у класса Student оставить только одно поле ArrayList<Integer> marks, и работать с ним

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете класс `Student`:

```
public class Student {
    private ArrayList<Integer> mMarks;

    public Student() {
        mMarks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMark(int mark) {
        mMarks.add(mark);
    }

    public float getAverageMark(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(Integer mark : mMarks)
            sum += mark;
        return (float) sum/mMarks.size();
    }
}
```

Далее создаете список студентов:

```
// Список студентов
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

// Первый студент
students.add(new Student());
students.get(0).addMark(4);
students.get(0).addMark(5);

// Второй студент
students.add(new Student());
students.get(1).addMark(3);
students.get(1).addMark(4);

for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("Студент №" + (i+1) + ". Средняя оценка: " + students.get(i).getAverageMark());
```

Разумеется нужно предусмотреть обработку исключений.

Comment: в методе `getAverageMark()` деление не правильно, надо заменить на  `return sum/  (float) mMarks.size()`, т.к. в вашем случае int разделить на int, будет целочисленное значение (неправильное, всегда без дробной части) и потом преобразовано в float

Comment: @MrFylypenko, Операция приведения типа имеет больший приоритет, чем операция деления, поэтому тут все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

- У студента должен быть список оценок. Метод `addMark(int examMark)` добавляет оценку к списку.
- Метод `getAverageMark()` итерируется по списку и считает среднюю оценку.
- Изменения в `Main()`зависят от того, как получаются данные о студентах и оценках. В общем случае будет цикл по некоторым "записям", для каждой записи создается экземпляр `Student`, добавляются оценки и считается среднее.